# Trying to make a web app with React Native based on my schools API, How would I go about making the Oauth2 Authorization Code flow?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, oauth-2.0, expo, authorization

Basically How I imagine the app to go, is having a modal with the Authorize Button, it redirects to the browser where you can authenticate from my schools website, and then redirects back to the app.

The thing is, I have no idea how to get the code from the redirect uri, in order to get the access token and let the user use the app while being authenticated.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!